# What is the best way to get data linked by a many to many relation?

Tags: c#, class

I have 5 classes. `User`, `Intern`, `Employee`, `Technician` and `Plumber`.

`Intern`, `Employee`, `Technician` and `Plumber` are all linked to `User` using a foreign key field and an object reference.

For `Plumber` it looks like this:

```
class Plumber
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PlumberNumber { get; set; }
    public User U { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public Plumber(int id, string plumbernumber, User user, int userid) 
    {
        Id = id;
        PlumberNumber = plumbernumber;
        U = user;
        UserId = userid;
    }
}
```

It has a link to the person class. This is the same for the other classes.
A user is either an `Intern` or an `Employee`, but can be both a `Plumber` and a `Technician`.

I eventually want to make 2 lists. A list of `Plumber` and a list of `Technician`. In this list I also want to be able to know if they are an `Intern` or `Employee` and display either their InternNumber or EmployeeNumber (These have different formats).

How can I link this all together?

I have tried using Linq to get info from the `Intern` and `Employee` list, based on the same UserId, but I feel like its not the proper way to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a mix of `inheritance` and `composition`.

Create an `abstract class` of type `User` and have two derived classes of type `Intern` and `Employee` inherit from that class. Then have an `Enum` encapsulating the `Plumber` and `Technician` roles and add these via `Composition`. I would then create a factory class to build these users.

Code is in Java but should be easily adaptable for C#.

User.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class User {
    protected final int userid;
    protected final ArrayList<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    public User(int userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public abstract void display();

    protected void setRole(Role role) {
        this.roles.add(role);
    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee extends User{

    private final int employeeNumber;

    public Employee(int userid, int employeeNumber) {
        super(userid);
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Employee with userid " + super.userid + " has employeenumber: " + this.employeeNumber);
        System.out.println("The user has the following roles: " + super.roles);
    }
}
```

Intern.java

```
public class Intern extends User{

    private final int internNumber;

    public Intern(int userid, int internNumber) {
        super(userid);
        this.internNumber = internNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("Intern with userid " + super.userid + " has internnumber: " + this.internNumber);
        System.out.println("The user has the following roles: " + super.roles);
    }
}
```

Role.java

```
public enum Role {
    Plumber,
    Technician
}
```

UserFactory.java

```
public class UserFactory {

    public static int userNumber = 1;
    public static int employeeNumber = 1;
    public static int internNumber = 1;

    public static User buildUser(String usertype, Role[] roles) {
        User user;
        switch (usertype) {

            case ("Employee") -> {
                user = new Employee(userNumber, employeeNumber);
                employeeNumber++;

            }
            case ("Intern") -> {
                user = new Intern(userNumber, internNumber);
                internNumber++;
                }
            default -> throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + usertype);
        }

        userNumber++;

        for(Role role:roles){
            user.setRole(role);
        }
        return user;

    }
}
```

You can then use these classes like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        User employee1 = UserFactory.buildUser("Employee", new Role[] {Role.Technician});
        User employee2 = UserFactory.buildUser("Employee", new Role[] {Role.Plumber, Role.Technician});
        User intern1 = UserFactory.buildUser("Intern", new Role[] {Role.Plumber});
        User intern2 = UserFactory.buildUser("Intern", new Role[] {Role.Plumber});

        userList.add(employee1);
        userList.add(employee2);
        userList.add(intern1);
        userList.add(intern2);

        //create new list with plumbers
        ArrayList<User> plumberList = new ArrayList<>();
        //create new list with technicians
        ArrayList<User> technicianlist = new ArrayList<>();

        for (User user:userList) {
            if (user.roles.contains(Role.Plumber)) {
                plumberList.add(user);
            }
            if (user.roles.contains(Role.Technician)) {
                technicianlist.add(user);
            }
        }

        for (User user:plumberList) {
                user.display();
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        for (User user:technicianlist) {
            user.display();
        }
    }
}
```

There's a few extra things you can do with C# like switching on type of object instead of string (afaik not possible in Java) and stuff with LINQ.